# Titanium mapview not working well

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm using Geocoder to to translate the address, given through a text field, in terms of latitude and longitude and then set the map region to that location as follows.

```
var location = Titanium.UI.createTextField({...});
var btnSearch = Titanium.UI.createButton({...});
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    top: 75,    height: 350,
    mapType: Titanium.Map.SATELLITE_TYPE,
    animate: true,  regionFit: true,    userLocation: true
});
btnSearch.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(location.value != '') {
        Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(location.value, function(e){
            Ti.API.info(location.value + '\'s co-ordinates are: ' + e.latitude + ' lat, ' + e.longitude + ' lon');
            mapview.region = {latitude: e.latitude, longitude: e.longitude, latitudeDelta:0.1, longitudeDelta:0.1};
        });
    } 
    else {
        alert('You must provide a start address!');
    }
});
```

The translation process works fine but the map region is not set to new coordinates in mapview. If anybody knows the cause of this problem, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
`mapview.setLocation({latitude: e.latitude, longitude: e.longitude, latitudeDelta:0.1, longitudeDelta:0.1});`